# How to use TransitionComponent in React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, typescript, transition, react-bootstrap, toast

I'd like to set transition props for ToastContainer to use transition animation for Toast notification.

transition should be TransitionComponent.

TransitionComponent looks like this;

```
export declare type TransitionComponent = React.ComponentType<{
    in?: boolean;
    appear?: boolean;
} & TransitionCallbacks>;
export declare type TransitionType = boolean | TransitionComponent;
```

I'd like to set transition like below;

```
export const Toast = ({ message, onClose }: Props) => {
  const messageRef = useRef<{
    head: string;
    body: string;
    detail?: string;
  }>({ head: "", body: "" });

  if (message) {
    messageRef.current = message;
  }

  return (
    <ToastContainer onClose={onClose} show={!!message} delay={7000} animation transition={transition}>
      <ToastHead>
        <strong className="mr-auto">{messageRef.current.head}</strong>
        <small>{messageRef.current?.detail}</small>
      </ToastHead>
      <ToastBody>{messageRef.current.body}</ToastBody>
    </ToastContainer>
  );
};
```

Question1: How can I define transition?

Question2: How can I write the transition inside JSX?

Any suggestions would be helpful!
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the typescript definition by including

```
import {TransitionComponent} from "react-bootstrap";
```

To use a transition, it looks like you import a `TransitionComponent` either from react-bootstrap, which includes [`Collapse` and `Fade`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/), or from the underlying package [react-transition-group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/).  You pass the whole component to `ToastContainer`.  If a `transition` prop is not included, it defaults to `Fade`.

```
import {Collapse, Toast as ToastContainer} from "react-bootstrap";

<ToastContainer onClose={onClose} show={!!message} delay={7000} animation transition={Collapse}>
```

Comment: Thank you Linda! I had not had the idea `Fade` is already set... Lol.  I tried to use Collapse followed your advice, but transition props has error.  ```Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<CollapseProps & RefAttributes<unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{ in?: boolean | undefined; appear?: boolean | undefined; } & TransitionCallbacks, any> | FunctionComponent<{ in?: boolean | undefined; appear?: boolean | undefined; } & TransitionCallbacks> | undefined'.```